# Why is the derivative of the Fermi-Dirac distribution negative?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, fermions

Why the derivative of Fermi-Dirac distribution function at absolute zero temperature becomes negative of Dirac_Delta function.
 The Fermi-Dirac distribution function is 
 \begin{equation}
 f_{0}(E)=\frac{1}{e^\frac{{E-E_{F}}}{k_{B}T}+1},
 \end{equation}
  As $T\rightarrow0$, the Fermi-Dirac distribution becomes a step function
\begin{equation}
f_{0}(E)=\Theta({E}-E_{F}).
\end{equation}
 and \begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial f_{0}}{\partial E}=\frac{-2}{\left(2\pi\hbar\right)^{3}}
\delta\left(E-E_{F}\right),
\end{equation}
how we can get this and why the derivative becomes negative? should it not be 
 \begin{equation}
 \frac{\partial f_{0}}{\partial E}=\frac{2}{\left(2\pi\hbar\right)^{3}}
\delta\left(E-E_{F}\right),
\end{equation}

Comment: Actually $\lim_{T\to 0} f_0(E) = \Theta(E_F-E)$. This means that only states below the Fermi energy are occupied. The derivative should be negative since the distribution goes from 1 to 0 when $E$ is increased above $E_F$. You should be able to convince yourself that the derivative must be negative at any temperature. It just means that lower-energy states are more likely to be occupied.

Comment: It's not clear how you define $\Theta(E)$, but you may have it inverted. Notice $f_0(E)\to{}1$ for $E\ll{}E_F$ and $f_0(E)\to{}0$ for $E\gg{}E_F$. Does your definition of $\Theta(E)$ do that?

Comment: @MarkMitchison that sounds like it should be an answer

Answer (score 5):

The Fermi-Dirac distribution is
$$ f_T(E)=\frac{1}{\exp\left(\frac{E-E_F}{k_{\text B}T}\right)+1}$$
when $T\to0$, the denominator of $\frac{E-E_F}{k_{\text B}T}$ goes to zero and this ratio goes to $+\infty$ if $E>E_F$ and to $-\infty$ if $<E_F$. Therefore the exponential $\exp\left(\frac{E-E_F}{k_{\text B}T}\right)$ goes to $0$ if $E<E_F$ and to $+\infty$ if $E>E_F$. Thus the distribution $f_0$ goes to $1$ if $E<E_F$ and to $0$ if $E>E_F$. This is expressed by the limiing expression
$$f_0=\Theta(E_F-E)$$ (and not $\Theta(E-E_F)$ as you wrote).

So the distribution $f_0$ is constant except at the point $E=E_F$ where it **decreases** from $1$ to $0$. That is why the derivative is negative.

By the way, we have $\frac{\partial f_0}{\partial E} =-\delta(E_F-E)$.

Comment: Why i cannot write \begin{equation}
f_{0}(E)=\Theta({E}-E_{F}).
\end{equation} Delta function is symmetric.

Comment: The letter $\Theta$ is called *theta*. Obviously, if $$\Theta(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}0&\text{if}\;x<0\\1&\text{if}\;x\geq 0\end{array}\right.$$ then it is not symmetric.